# Android widget that requires data fetching only shows loading

Tags: android, kotlin, android-widget, android-launcher

I am trying to add a widget in view by an android widget picker. A simple analog clock widget is displayed correctly but widget, where data have to fetch, is only showing loading without showing data as in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot]

My widget creation code is done from [Hosting Android Widget](https://www.leonardofischer.com/hosting-android-widgets-my-appwidgethost-tutorial/).

My code is :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var mAppWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager
lateinit var mAppWidgetHost: AppWidgetHost
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    mAppWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this)
    mAppWidgetHost = AppWidgetHost(this, APPWIDGET_HOST_ID)
    add_widget.setOnClickListener {
        selectWidget()
    }
}

fun selectWidget() {
    val appWidgetId = mAppWidgetHost.allocateAppWidgetId()
    val pickIntent = Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK)
    pickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    addEmptyData(pickIntent)
    startActivityForResult(pickIntent, REQUEST_PICK_APPWIDGET)
}

private fun addEmptyData(pickIntent: Intent) {
    val customInfo = arrayListOf<Parcelable>()
    pickIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_CUSTOM_INFO, customInfo)
    val customExtras = arrayListOf<Parcelable>()
    pickIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_CUSTOM_EXTRAS, customExtras)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_APPWIDGET) {
            configureWidget(data)
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CREATE_APPWIDGET) {
            createWidget(data)
        }
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED && data != null) {
        val appWidgetId = data.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1)
        if (appWidgetId != -1) {
            mAppWidgetHost.deleteAppWidgetId(appWidgetId)
        }
    }
}

private fun configureWidget(data: Intent?) {
    val extras = data?.extras ?: return
    val appWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1)
    val appWidgetInfo = mAppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(appWidgetId)
    if (appWidgetInfo.configure != null) {
        val intent = Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE)
        intent.component = appWidgetInfo.configure
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId)
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CREATE_APPWIDGET)
    } else {
        createWidget(data)
    }
}


private fun createWidget(data: Intent?) {
    val extras = data?.extras ?: return;
    val appWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1);
    val appWidgetInfo = mAppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(appWidgetId);
    val hostView = mAppWidgetHost.createView(this, appWidgetId, appWidgetInfo);
    remove_widget.setOnClickListener {
        removeWidget(hostView)
    }
    hostView.setAppWidget(appWidgetId, appWidgetInfo);
    widgetLayout.addView(hostView);
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    mAppWidgetHost.startListening()
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    mAppWidgetHost.stopListening()
}

private fun removeWidget(hostView: AppWidgetHostView) {
    mAppWidgetHost.deleteAppWidgetId(hostView.appWidgetId)
    widgetLayout.removeView(hostView);
}

companion object {
    const val REQUEST_PICK_APPWIDGET = 9
    const val REQUEST_REFRESH_APPWIDGET = 10
    const val APPWIDGET_HOST_ID = 442
    const val REQUEST_CREATE_APPWIDGET = 5
}
}
```

Here, remove_widget and add_widget are button and widgetLayout is linearlayout to add widget.

edit:
The following error is shown in log after adding gmail widget.

`2019-11-28 14:18:33.652 15363-15363/com.example.testapplication W/AppWidgetHostView: Error inflating RemoteViews : android.widget.RemoteViews$ActionException: android.widget.RemoteViews$ActionException: view: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView can't use method with RemoteViews: setImageResource(int)`

note: from another launcher, widget is rendering as expected, not from my code though. Also, I changed my context with applicationContext. But, it produces same result.

Comment: Do either the createWidget or configureWidget functions ever get called? Could you do printlns and see if they are being called as/when expected?

Comment: Yes, both create and configure is being called properly, but there was an exception in log after adding gmail widget. I have updated the question, please look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using androidX AppCompactActivity, then try to use normal activity and see if that works.

```
import android.app.Activity;


//other codes....

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // other codes...

}
```

Comment: Yes, it works with activity. Probably as Remoteviews is using appcompat views rather than android app views.

Answer (score 0):

** RemoteViews is limited to support for the following layouts:

- AdapterViewFlipper
- FrameLayout
- GridLayout
- GridView
- LinearLayout
- ListView
- RelativeLayout
- StackView
- ViewFlipper

** And the following widgets:

- AnalogClock
- Button
- Chronometer
- ImageButton
- ImageView
- ProgressBar
- TextClock
- TextView

** Descendants of these classes are not supported.

You should review your layout!

Comment: I am not implementing remote views myself. I am loading a widget from the widget picker and adding it in a linear layout view, so I think there is no problem in my layout.